# I'm not getting database data into my activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get firebase data to the profile activity, but it is not working:

```
 user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Registered Users").child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            Users userProfile = snapshot.getValue(Users.class);

            if(snapshot.exists()){
                if(userProfile != null)
                {
                    String fullName = userProfile.name;
                    String userName = userProfile.username;
                   // String person = userProfile.person_type;

                    name.setText(fullName);
                    username.setText(userName);
} 
}
```

[image]

I got no error but not working. I have tried to debug, I first thought that the reason is that the user is not logged in. but I added an if condition and printed whether the user is logged in or not, and it turns out that the user is logged in.

the issue I have is `reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener){}`is not getting executed. I tried printing toast messages but they don't show. so the complier is not going inside this function and I don't know why.

I tried this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://petsapplication-e68fd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").getReference("Registered Users")
```

and I got `google-services.json` downloaded with the right url.
Note that login and signup are working just fine and data get saved into the. database but I face the issue when I try to get the data..

my code has no errors and I'm expected to get data from firebase into textView. but nothing is retrieved

Comment: Questions that only say "[it doesn't work](https://overflow.tips/problematic-questions#why-doesnt-it-work--what-am-i-missing-here)" are problematic for Stack Overflow and likely to be [closed](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed) as needing debugging information.  Your question should explain what specifically doesn't work the way you expect, along with what you've done to debug the problem so far.

Comment: Is any other interaction from the app with the database working? If not, you might have downloaded a `google-services.json` file that doesn't include the (correct) database URL. If that is the case/cause, you can either download an updated file **or** pass the URL in your code with: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://petsapplication-e68fd-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com").getReference("Registered Users")`

Comment: I updated my question and added more details to it. I hope now you can help me better.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: I already did, please check my edit